# how to use view jquery plugin output?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

im beginner in jquery plugin. how do i display the output of these code?

```
test = (function ($) {
    $.test.testingfunction = function(option) {
        var setting = $.extend({},$test.testingfunction.default,option);

        return $.parseJSON(this.setting);
    }

    $.test.testingfunction.default = {
        ayam: "chicken",
        itik: "duck"
    }

    $.test.testingfunction.default.ayam="lembu";

    //$output = $.parseJSON($.fn.testingfunction({kambing:"goat",ikan:"fish"}));
    //return $output;
});

alert($.test());
```

i try to display output of test function.